# Nuget package manager don't add any reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

I'm trying to Microsoft.Windows.Ocr from nuget package to my Project, it adds it, but there are no reference added.

I'm clueless of what the probleme is.

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, that's because your project is not UWP(Universal Windows Project).

You have to create from a project template named with `(Universal Windows)`.

`Microsoft.Windows.Ocr` package is UWP library so only runnable with UWP app. For this reason, your development environment would be Windows 10 also.

Comment: Thanks for the information this helped a lot. But where did it show it's UWP exclusive ?

Comment: @PLAudet // if you select a package, `Dependencies` section tells its applicable platform in general. But in your case, only package `Description` section tells its platforms (UWP) as it does not have any dependencies.